# How to assign names to the LLVM IR instructions?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I am trying to the get the operand name for the instruction such `%10 = load i32* %2, align 4, !dbg !140'. But, it is giving` empty string' for the operands which are named as %1, %2 like this.
Therefore, in order to get the names of the instructions I need to assign names to them (suggested by other posts). Please help me by letting know the procedure of assigning names to the LLVM IR instruction.

Comment: Are you talking about IR you generate yourself or IR generated by another compiler/tool?

Answer (score 1):

There is `instnamer` opt pass. So, simply running `opt -instnamer <your IR> -o out.bc` will produce the IR with all instructions named.